# Install libmysqlclient on CentOs 7

Tags: centos, mysql

I am trying to build mysql-shell 1.0.11 from src.  RPMs are not an option when I am installing.  One of the requirements is `libmysqlclient 5.7+`.  I have installed `mysql++`, `mysql++-devel`, `mysql-connector-python.noarch`, and `mysql-workbench-community`.  When I try to build (Cmake) I get the following error.

```
Could not find static "libmysqlclient_r.a libmysqlclient.a" in MYSQL_LIB_DIR
```

What do I need to have installed to make this work?  Obviously I need libmysqlclient, but there is nothing listed in yum with that name or close to that name.

Using CentOs7.

TIA

Comment: sudo yum install mysql-devel ; maybe need some repository first. (Google search)

Answer (score 10):

Try `yum install mariadb-devel` for CentOS 7

Comment: the only one that worked! thanks

Comment: The only one that worked for me too!

Answer (score 9):

yum whatprovides can find package with specific command or lib, for example:

```
sudo yum whatprovides libmysqlclient*

1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.i686 : The shared libraries required for
                                 : MariaDB/MySQL clients
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Provides    : libmysqlclient.so.18
Provides    : libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)
Provides    : libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
```

and

```
sudo yum install mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.i686
```

But I'm not sure it's a good idea to install mysql-shell from src, when you can get with simple **yum install mysql**

Answer (score 2):

```
# find / -name libmysqlclient.so
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
# ln -s /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so
```

Comment: Bijaya, rather than dump a list of commands, it'd be helpful if you explained what you did and why you think it would solve the problem at hand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

Install packages:

```
yum install mariadb mariadb-server mariadb-devel mariadb-libs luarocks lua-devel
yum group install "Development Tools"
luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/mysql MYSQL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib64/mysql
```

And finally got something:

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/luasql-mysql-2.4.0-1.src.rock...
Using https://luarocks.org/luasql-mysql-2.4.0-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
gcc -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -c src/luasql.c -o src/luasql.o -I/usr/include/mysql
gcc -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -c src/ls_mysql.c -o src/ls_mysql.o -I/usr/include/mysql
gcc -shared -o luasql/mysql.so -L/usr/lib64/lua/5.1 src/luasql.o src/ls_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64/mysql -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/mysql: -lmysqlclient
Updating manifest for /usr/lib64/luarocks/rocks
No existing manifest. Attempting to rebuild...
luasql-mysql 2.4.0-1 is now built and installed in /usr (license: MIT/X11)
```

Installed:

```
# luarocks list
Installed rocks:
----------------
luasql-mysql
   2.4.0-1 (installed) - /usr/lib64/luarocks/rocks
```

Comment: I see that you've compiled a mysql package of some sort and linked it against a mysqlclient library, but you aren't showing how to install libmysqlclient to begin with, which is what this OP is asking about...